# Swift sender tint color

Tags: xcode, swift, sender, tint

I'm working on a tic tac toe game where each square is its own button and the image of the button changes when the square is tapped. I have done this by connecting all of the square buttons to the same IBAction `@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)` and by using `sender.setImage()` to change the image. The problem is, the images are all blue. I can change this blue to a different color by changing the global tint color, but what I really want is for the O and X images to be different colors. `sender.tintColor` throws an error and `button.tintColor`, as I have in the code below, just changes the color of one image back and forth every time a square is tapped. I have tried setting the global tint to no color in the File Inspector, but it just goes back to the default blue. Any thoughts?

```
if activePlayer == 1 {

    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "o-img"), forState: .Normal)

    activePlayer = 2

    button.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

} else {

    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "x-img"), forState: .Normal)

    activePlayer = 1

    button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, changing the button type from 'System' to 'Custom' removes the tint. Hope that helps someone else who came across the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

When you drag the image to the view controller's code to connect, before clicking "Ok" change the sender to UIImage instead of AnyObject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the button so the next player can not tap on it.

```
sender.enabled = false
```

Comment: This returns with an error code: Value of type ‘AnyObject’ has no member ‘enabled’.